# How to render index.html using python Flask MVC

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

This is absolutely new field for me, and I just confused about how this work

Flask server

```
$ more flask-hello-world.py 
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html') #"Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
$ more index.html 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>untitled</title>
</head>
<body>

Hello worlds
</body>
</html>
```

Test

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:5000
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

When I `return "Hello World!"` it does work properly. Why am I getting an error when I try `return render_template('index.html')`?

Comment: Could you share your project structure?

Comment: I tried that too, to avail, all the files are in the same folder ...  Actually that might very well be the issue ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you should [turn on debugging for your Flask app](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#debug-mode), so you see a meaningful error instead of a canned *HTTP 500 Internal Server Error*.

```
app.debug = True
app.run()
```

or

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

### What could be wrong with your Flask app

From your source code I see you have not imported `render_template`

So that is at least one issue, fix it with:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
# The rest of your file here
```

**Template names and directory**

There is a parameter [`template_folder`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask)
 you can use to tell Flask where to look for your templates. According to linked documentation, that value defaults to `templates` which means Flask by default looks for templates in a folder called `templates` by default. So if your templates are on the project root instead of a folder, use:

E.g. if your templates are in the same directory is the app:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='.') # '.' means the current directory
```

Comment: I put the `.py` and the `index.html` in the same folder ... that's the problem right ?! the templates should go a special folder?

Comment: Yes `templates` is the default, but I provided code for it to look for the templates in the same folder as the flask app

Answer (score 3):

You need to put your templates in `templates` folder, or ovride it in:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='.')
```

Comment: that's it that was part of my issue. Cheers mate.